# How can I access a JavaScript object which has spaces in the object's key?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a JavaScript object that looks something like this:

```
var myTextOptions = {
  'cartoon': {
     comic: 'Calvin & Hobbes',
     published: '1993'
  },
  'character names': {
    kid: 'Calvin',
    tiger: 'Hobbes'
  }
}
```

I can access the properties of `cartoon` easily using `myTextOptions.cartoon.comic` or whatever. However, I haven't been able to get the syntax right for accessing `kid`. I've tried the following with no luck:

```
myTextOptions.character names.kid
myTextOptions."character names".kid
myTextOptions.character\ names.kid
myTextOptions.'character names'.kid
myTextOptions.["character names"].kid
myTextOptions.character%20names.kid
```

Comment: In Google Chrome, if you go to inspect element and then hover over the json file data sets, each individual data set will have a tooltip appear showing it's path and it also gives you the option to copy the path into your clipboard. Just an FYI.

Comment: more... When I type myTextOptions.character%20n.kid returns 'NaN'. The last property name (kid) doen't matter, should be any other.

I'm using FireFox Quantum 8.3.0esr (64-bits) on Debian 9

Answer (score 299, accepted):

Use ECMAscript's "bracket notation":

```
myTextOptions[ 'character names' ].kid;
```

You can use that notation either way, reading & writing.

For more information read here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: julio mentions in the OP that he'd already tried using `myTextOptions.["character names"].kid` - for completeness to this question, I was wondering why that didn't work?

Comment: @James_F Because he also used the `dot notation` simultaneously. There must only be one accessor directive.

Comment: oh, yes, sorry - was looking so hard I didn't see the extra dot before the bracket! - thanks

Comment: Does somebody know if it is a good or bad practice use spaces in object keys?

Comment: @JuanP.Ortiz, This is not a good practice if you are using typescript, you will lose typescript compile check.

Comment: @RosdiKasim -- to add, one can use [key: type]: any in typescript. i.e. original key "My Id" which is a string so, can declare "[My_Id: string]: any" in interface;

Answer (score 7):

Properties of JavaScript objects can also be accessed or set using a bracket notation (for more details see [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)). Objects are sometimes called associative arrays since each property is associated with a string value that can be used to access it. So, for example, you could access the properties of the myCar object as follows:

```
myCar['make'] = 'Ford';
myCar['model'] = 'Mustang';
myCar['year'] = 1969;
```

For more, read on at [Working with JS Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

So in your case it's `myTextOptions['character names'].kid;`

Answer (score 6):

We can also do this by -

`myTextOptions[ 'character names' ]['kid']`;

This is useful when we have consecutive keys which consist of space.

Answer (score 3):

Let me share my solution here 
I am using VueJs with type script.

I got following json to parse and display in UI

```
 {
    "Brand": "MAMA",
    "Variety": "Instant Noodles Coconut Milk Flavour",
    "Style": "Pack",
    "Country": "Myanmar",
    "Stars": 5,
    "Top Ten": "2016 #10"
  },
```

I have created the following model interfere in Typescript

```
export interface Resto {
    Brand: string;
    Variety: string;
    Style: string;
    Country: string;
    Stars: any;
    Top_Ten: string;
    }
```

I have called the API as:

```
   public async getListOfRestos() {
    return (await fetch(
      `http://starlord.hackerearth.com/TopRamen`,
      {
        method: "get",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: undefined
      }
    )) as IFetchResponse<Resto[]>;
  }
```

Used in JSX like:

```
 <div class="parent" v-for="(x,i) in listOfRestos" :key="i">
      <div>{{x.Brand}}</div>
      <div>{{x.Variety}}</div>
      <div>{{x.Style}}</div>
      <div>{{x.Country}}</div>
      <div>{{x.Stars}}</div>
      <div>{{x['Top Ten']}}</div>
  </div>
```

Same can also work in React and Angular.