# Cannot access property with space in name

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
 translations = {
      'nl': {
            'Dashboard': [
            {
                "Today's turnover": "Omzet van vandaag",
                "Get an overview directly from your receipts on location.": "Bekijk een overzicht rechtstreeks vanuit uw inkomsten op locatie.",
                "Choose your POS provider": "Kies uw POS provider"
            }],
            'Products': [],
            'Order': []
        }

    }
```

And I'm trying to access the `Today's turnover` property of the `Dashboard` proprty inside `nl`, which, according to the question and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317982/access-javascript-object-with-space-in-key) can be accessed like `object['object property']` However when I try to access it, it comes as undefined for some reason:

[image]

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dashboard is an array, and your object is the first element in this array. Also you don't have to escape `'`  if you are in a `""` string!

So use this:

```
translations['nl']['Dashboard'][0]["Today's turnover"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Check below code its working for `object['object property']`, may be you are using some wrong key name

```js
translations = {
  'nl': {
    'Dashboard': [{
      "Today's turnover": "Omzet van vandaag",
      "Get an overview directly from your receipts on location.": "Bekijk een overzicht rechtstreeks vanuit uw inkomsten op locatie.",
      "Choose your POS provider": "Kies uw POS provider"
    }],
    'Products': [],
    'Order': []
  }

}

document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML = translations['nl']['Dashboard'][0]['Today\'s turnover'];
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this not working?

Because you are not using the exact name of the property, but for some reason decided to add an extra backslash …

Answer (score 1):

`Dashboard` is a `Array`, not `Object`. To access it, you must:

```
translations['n1']['Dashboard'][0]['Today\'s turnover']
```

Or:

```
translations.n1.Dashboard[0]['Today\'s turnover']
```

Answer (score 0):

`Dashboard` is an array. So use `Dashboard[0]`

```
translations = {
      'nl': {
            'Dashboard': [
            {
                "Today's turnover": "Omzet van vandaag",
                "Get an overview directly from your receipts on location.": "Bekijk een overzicht rechtstreeks vanuit uw inkomsten op locatie.",
                "Choose your POS provider": "Kies uw POS provider"
            }],
            'Products': [],
            'Order': []
        }

    }

console.log(translations.nl.Dashboard[0]['Today\'s turnover']);
```

**Note**

`[ ]` is use to retrieve `Today's turnover` key instead of `dot(.)` notation.
You can check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) for more information

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/htrhxvjp/)

Answer (score 0):

A bit of theory to back other good answers here.

Properties of JavaScript objects can also be accessed or set using a bracket notation (for more details see [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)). Objects are sometimes called associative arrays, since each property is associated with a string value that can be used to access it. So, for example, you could access the properties of the myCar object as follows:

```
myCar['make'] = 'Ford';
myCar['model'] = 'Mustang';
myCar['year'] = 1969;
```

For more, read on at [Working with JS Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).