# How to change values in javascript when it's deep nested and the keys have spaces

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have seen the answer here:

[access javascript object with space in key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317982/access-javascript-object-with-space-in-key)

But what would you do if

```
const parent = { "A B": 
  {
   "1 2": "Hello",
   "3": "World"
  }
}
```

How would you change "Hello" to Hi?

Comment: I would first get rid of the unnecessary and confusing use of `const`, then I would say `parent["A B"]["1 2"] = "Hi"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just the same, by multiple bracket notations in a row.

```js
const parent = { "A B": 
  {
   "1 2": "Hello",
   "3": "World"
  }
}

parent["A B"]["1 2"] = 'Hi';

console.log(parent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use brackets:

```
parent["A B"]["1 2"] = 'Hi';
```