# Javascript - Retrieve Data from the DOM

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get data from the DOM using Javascript.

My tree is:
 `this.caseCodingList.grid.store.__proto__.index`

I need to retrieve one of the IDs from the index. It doesn't matter which. Here are various things I have tried, but failed on.

Attempt One:

```
var grid = this.caseCodingList.grid;
var row = grid.store.getPrototypeOf(data).get(0);
```

Attempt Two:

```
var row = grid.store.getData();
```

Attempe Three:

```
var index = grid.store.__proto__.index
```

This one does return something, but I am not able to extract what I want. I also don't know if it will be cross browser compatible. I am developing mainly with Chrome.
Results:

```
{871: 3, {A9A1B512-8E93-4131-B9CD-85C1AEF04722}: 0, {C249D8F2-4561-4657-A6CF-039C0DC89898}: 1, {82FDAFEA-6DCC-483C-BEB7-DDF37818A4C5}: 2}
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: ```__proto__``` is not how you want to be referencing those values.

Comment: what about `grid.store.index`?

Comment: @JonathanRys - Yeah I know, but that is the only thing I could get to work.  My question is how do I reference them?

Comment: See also [__proto__ VS. prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/215552) for more on `__proto__`.

Comment: @vzwick Thanks! That answers part of my question. It returns: `{871: 3, {A9A1B512-8E93-4131-B9CD-85C1AEF04722}: 0, {C249D8F2-4561-4657-A6CF-039C0DC89898}: 1, {82FDAFEA-6DCC-483C-BEB7-DDF37818A4C5}: 2}` - How do I retrieve just one of those values?

Comment: @staples - which one of the values do you want?

Comment: @vzwick - I want the `{ID}: 0` value

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json and https://stackoverflow.com/q/8317982/215552

Comment: @staples - so, any `id` where the corresponding `value` is 0? The first one? The last one? All of them?

Comment: @vzwick - yes, any id that has the value of 0.  In the end though, it doesn't matter which one I use - This is the case for everytime it is used.

Comment: What does this have to do with the DOM? Are you sure you know what DOM means …?

Comment: @staples - see my answer.

Comment: @vzwick - thanks.  I will give it a go

Comment: @misorude - maybe not. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const index = grid.store.index;
const idOfObjectWithZeroEntries = Object
    .keys(index)
    .find(x => index[x] === 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time in understanding my issue! I had to change `const` to `var` to get it to work, but not a big deal. Again, thanks!