# How to display data from a JSON having parameters with spaces in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am trying to display the data from this JSON API, I have no problem getting it, but when I display the parameters with the space reflected in the image, it returns nothing. How can I show those values? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access a JavaScript object which has spaces in the object's key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317982/how-can-i-access-a-javascript-object-which-has-spaces-in-the-objects-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat the json as an associative array

```
json['Precio Gasoleo A']
// ie:
ListaEESSPrecio[0]['Precio Gasoleo A']
```