# Javascript nested object key with space

Tags: javascript

How can I use the below syntax for nested object key if my object keys have spaces ?

```
var level3 = (((test || {}).level1 || {}).level2 || {}).level3;
alert( level3 );
```

So above works, but say if level1 key is actually "level 1", how can I get the above syntax to work ?

Comment: `var level3 = (((test || {})["level 1"] || {}).level2 || {}).level3;`

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317982/how-can-i-access-a-javascript-object-which-has-spaces-in-the-objects-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317982/how-can-i-access-a-javascript-object-which-has-spaces-in-the-objects-key)

Comment: `level3 = test?.["level 1"]?.["level 2"]?.["level 3"]`

Comment: @RickyMo - Thank you...that seems to work....

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin - I think this is the optional chaining syntax...While this would work, the only concern is cross-browser support (even though I don't need to support IE, but other modern ones)